# Sort Linked List with Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, comparator

I have a question. Please take a look at my code below,
when i want to sort data on linked list by using collections.sort and comparator will working after write (collections.sort (...)) and then use it again with comparator?

Is it possible to just use a comparator without collection.sort (...) first?

```
  final LinkedList unsorted = new LinkedList(lList);

  Collections.sort(unsorted);

  Collections.sort(unsorted, 
            new Comparator<String>() { 
            @Override public int compare(String s1, String s2) { 
                return s1.length() - s2.length(); 
            } 
        } ); 
  System.out.println("LinkedList (after sorting using Comparator): " + unsorted);
```

And can someone give me a suggest how to separate the comparator sort by method, I mean that is separate from the main method.

Output that I want :

```
Unsorted [75, 2, 0, 1, 10, 25, 60, 40, 70, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 15]
LinkedList (after sorting using Comparator): [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 10, 15, 25, 40, 60, 70, 75]
```

Thank you

Comment: Lists are inherently unsorted collections, because they implement the queue interface, which requires LIFO behavior.  If you want a collection which maintains sort order along the way, consider using `TreeSet`.

Comment: You can directly run `Collections.sort(unsorted, comparator)` to sort your list. You may use `TreeMap` or `TreeSet` (if there is no duplicated elements) to make it sorted automatically during adding new elements.

Comment: Oh okay, I quite understand now.
So thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your code .

```
 Integer[] ints = {75, 2, 0, 1, 10, 25, 60, 40, 70, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 15};
 List<Integer> lList = Arrays.asList(ints);
 final LinkedList unsorted = new LinkedList(lList);

 Collections.sort(unsorted);

 System.out.println("LinkedList (after sorting using Comparator): " + unsorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can discard the initial call to `Collections.sort()` and simply call it once with the comparator!

You could save the comparator to a static field and pass the field to `Collections.sort()`

However, you must provide some way of telling the jvm how to order elements (unless you switch to a list of integer). See Edit:

As a final note, a sort on a linked list is expensive due to it's linear complexity (it has to iterate every node in the worst case), consider using something like `TreeSet` as previously suggested

Edit: If ascending order is sufficient, a string sort without a comparator will work as expected if all strings are numeric!

Also your comparator is working on string length, so this will not sort the list in ascending order as expected

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but can you give me the code for the create static field and pass it to Collection.sort()?